# \begin{list} ... \end{list} without elements

Tags: lists

In some generated code I got that the begin and end tag of a `list` were given but no `item` i.e.

```
\begin{list}{}{}
\end{list}
```

This leads to the message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

It is clear that this is due to a missing `\item`, but as it is generated code there are 2 possibilities:

- the begin and end tag are not generated in case of no items present (preferred solution, but hard to find all places in the code)
- adding an option to `\begin{list}` to make it possible to have no items, does this exist?

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
% working
\begin{list}{}{}
\item the item
\end{list}
% giving error
\begin{list}{}{}

\end{list}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the `list` environment takes *two* mandatory arguments, the syntax is `\begin{list}{<label>}{<commands>} ... \end{list}`.  This won’t solve the problem, though, since you’ll now get the (correct! ;-) error message `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`.

Comment: Please tell us more about the ultimate typographic objective you're looking to achieve. LaTeX's `list` environment is a very low-level tool; most user-level list-like environments might build on and make use of the `list` environment, but they usually provide a lot of additional functionality for users. There may be better tools out there for you than the `list` environment. In short, do tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mico this is generated code by doxygen for general lists (already packed in an own environment setting some lengths).

Comment: What should happen, exactly, when an empty list occurs?  In particular, should some amount of vertical space be added between the text that comes before and that that follows?

Comment: @GuM for the time being nothing should happen (so more or less ignoring the `\begin` and `\end`), but an answer with just a giving some space (or a text like "Empty List" ) would be preferred as it would give a direction for further development.

Comment: What is the source code (are you doing this from C++?) that is causing this empty list to be generated? It would seem to make more senes to find out why doxygen is creating an empty list, than to try and hack around it.

Comment: @PeterFlynn Theer are 2 points in this question: 1) circumvent that the situation can happen (i.e. in doxygen see to it that it cannot happen), this has been implemented in the master version now (and hopefully all places are covered). 2) general possibility in case situations as 1) are to difficult / error prone, this has been answered by GuM.

Comment: Excellent — I was just curious to know what the source problem was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Caveat emptor

You could try this, but please note that it is a ***really crude hack:***

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\patchcmd\endtrivlist
    {\if@newlist \@noitemerr \global\@newlistfalse \fi}
    {}
    {}{}
\patchcmd\endtrivlist
    {\@endparenv}
    {\if@newlist \@endpefalse \global\@newlistfalse \else \@endparenv \fi}
    {}{}

\makeatother



\begin{document}
Text before
\begin{list}{--}{}
\item the item
    \item another item
    \item \begin{itemize}
            \item a sublist
            \item second subitem
        \end{itemize}
    \item back to outer level
\end{list}
Text after

Text before
\begin{list}{--}{}
\end{list}
Text after\\
another line\\
still another\\
and another

\end{document}
```